# How to run "above" chunks including child documents in from parent RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, parent-child

I have a `main` Rmd file which calls several `children` Rmd files via the `child` chunk option, such as the following:

---

````
# (main Rmd)

```{r run child 01, child="child_01.Rmd"}
```

```{r run child 02, child="child_02.Rmd"}
```

<--- working here interactively!
````

---

````
# (child 01 Rmd)

```{r }
print("child 01")
```
````

---

````
# (child 02 Rmd)

```{r }
print("child 02")
```
````

Knitting such a document works as expected, but when working interactively after the `run child 02` chunk. Is there any way to run all "above" chunks including all children and, of course, those chunks from the main document as well?

I ([and](https://community.rstudio.com/t/best-way-to-run-child-markdowns-and-or-bookdown-chapters-interactively-in-rstudio/46495) [others](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-run-all-chunks-across-all-documents-in-a-bookdown-project/5557)) expected that the `Run all chunks above` would include children documents, but that is not the case. So I am looking for a workaround.

Preferably, a good workaround would not require duplicating the list of children files in the correct order (specially that, in general, there might be code between children documents in the main document). Also, opening all children documents and runnning in the correct order is not feasible in a large project.

BTW, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2417